# Use a auto incremented number across multiple lists

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

As we use lots of sites which all have their own issue list to track issues per project, i was wondering whether it's possible to add a column to these lists (to their content type) which automatically adds a number which is unique across all lists/sites.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Lists have a Unique ID attached to each item (hidden field) that you could potentially use, but you will have to come up with a custom solution if you don't want ID's to be duplicated across your site collection.
One thought is to attach a workflow to each list you want unique ID's for, and copy the content to a separate list.  This will create the unique ID's you are after.

List 1 > Workflow > ContainerList with unique ID

List 2 > Workflow > ContainerList with unique ID

While the originating lists will have their own 'unique' ID's, the TRUE unique ID you are after will be contained in the "Container" list.  As each item is added, the workflow will create a duplicate item in the "Container" list, which will also have a unique ID assigned to it.  This way, all lists with the attached workflow will have a separate ID in the "Container" list you can utilize.  Messy, but it works.